# Why is that Thread interupt method is not breaking its sleep method?

Tags: multithreading

I have this program below

```
package com;
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Into sleep");
                Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                System.out.println("Out of sleep");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadDemo tD = new ThreadDemo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tD);
        t1.start();
        t1.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I have started the Thread , and will call its run method and goes into sleep state for the above specified seconds .

i have called  `t1.interrupt();`

This is the screen shot

[image]

My question is that why

**1.The Thread is not coming out of sleep state ?**

2. Why `Into sleep` is printed twice ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in a loop:

- You're sleeping
- Being interrupted and printing the stack trace
- Going back to sleep
- Never being interrupted again

So it *is* "coming out of sleep state" (otherwise you wouldn't see the stack trace) - but you're then calling `Thread.sleep` again.

If you only want to sleep once, get rid of the loop...

Comment: :)  I would never have found out this .Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

1.The Thread is not comng out of sleep state ?

He actually is but

```
System.out.println("Out of sleep");
```

is never executed because when you interrupt Thread.sleep(10000); throws a exception and

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

is execute instead